# JPA query works with number but not with Integer variable

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I have written some code for retrieving a list of Object from a postgres db.
The query gives me correct result if I write the value of id_utente_pres (for example 68) in the criteria. But if I use the Integer variable called "id" the result set is empty.

Code that retreive the correct result set:

```
public List<Prenotazione> getPrenotazioni(Integer id) throws RemoteException {
    Session session;
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Prenotazione> criteria = builder.createQuery(Prenotazione.class);
    Root<Prenotazione> prenotazioneFind = criteria.from(Prenotazione.class);
    criteria.select(prenotazioneFind);

    ParameterExpression<Integer> p = builder.parameter(Integer.class);
    criteria.where(builder.equal(prenotazioneFind.get("id_utente_pren"), 68));
    List<Prenotazione> prenotazioniUtente = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    session.close();
    return prenotazioniUtente;
}
```

Generated sql:
Hibernate: select prenotazio0_.id_prenotazione as id_preno1_6_, prenotazio0_.dataprenotazione as datapren2_6_, prenotazio0_.id_libro as id_libro3_6_, prenotazio0_.id_utente_pren as id_utent4_6_ from table_prenotazioni prenotazio0_ where prenotazio0_.id_utente_pren=68

Code that returns an empty result set:

```
public List<Prenotazione> getPrenotazioni(Integer id) throws RemoteException {
    Session session;
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();

    CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Prenotazione> criteria = builder.createQuery(Prenotazione.class);
    Root<Prenotazione> prenotazioneFind = criteria.from(Prenotazione.class);
    criteria.select(prenotazioneFind);

    ParameterExpression<Integer> p = builder.parameter(Integer.class);
    criteria.where(builder.equal(prenotazioneFind.get("id_utente_pren"), id));
    List<Prenotazione> prenotazioniUtente = session.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
    session.close();
    return prenotazioniUtente;
}
```

Generated sql:
Hibernate: select prenotazio0_.id_prenotazione as id_preno1_6_, prenotazio0_.dataprenotazione as datapren2_6_, prenotazio0_.id_libro as id_libro3_6_, prenotazio0_.id_utente_pren as id_utent4_6_ from table_prenotazioni prenotazio0_ where prenotazio0_.id_utente_pren=?

Comment: What is the type of `id` and what is its value?

Comment: Hi, id is an Integer and its value is 68

Comment: PostgreSQL (in his native driver) has some attention to length of integers. Log with generated SQL can be helpfull, BTW we are happy if Yuo show real code with `id`

Comment: Hi and tank yuou all, i've updated the code with the entire procedure. In the DB the table the "id_utente_pren" is an Integer.

Comment: Hi all, i've debugged the id variable, and the problem was there, because they wasnt initialized in another procedure. thank you all.